# How to make @Override compulsory for subclasses?

Tags: java, oop

An example: In Android usually when you try to override a method of Activity super class, you have to have @Override annotation, it is compulsory. How do they do that?

I want to impose strictly use @Override in my subclss overriding methods. What changes I need to do in parent class to impose this?

I want to enforce the annotation (not just override base methods).

Comment: I don't think you can do it with code - there may be something in your IDE (for example Netbeans shows a warning if the annotation is missing) or you could use a style analysis tool such as checkstyle or findbugs that probably have a rule to check for that annotation.

Comment: I think you're asking about enforcing the annotation, but the answers think that you're trying to force people to override your base methods. Therefore, the question is obviously unclear. Please clarify.

Comment: This is not compulsory in Android. The only thing that may happen is that Android Studio is set to complain that you didn't put that annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a code quality checking tool during CI, but you might have to build your own (which is a task of medium complexity), or add the feature to one of the existing code quality checkers. Then you simply fail the build if the annotation isn't there.

Comment: Sounds completely feasible. I'm accepting it with +1. And Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the @override annotation, I've made plugins that "Need them" without it.

Comment: Do didn't understand the question. override is not compulsory, yes indeed, but I want to enforce strict use of override.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to force override this means that the parent implementation of the method will be hidden for sure. So it won't be called in any case, unless from the overridden method itself.

This means that you can just declare the method `abstract` (together with the `class`):

```
abstract class Foo {
  public abstract void overrideMe();
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: I don't think you explained your question well enough. If the question is "how I can enforce the @Override annotation on subclasses" it seems just an XY problem to me. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to force override on anyone. If you make the class or method `abstract`, then yes the override is compulsory. But then you do not provide your implementation you want your subclasses and/or unlucky maintenance drones to follow and derive their own override based on. And if the class is not abstract, nobody is forced to override anything and can use your original method as much as they like.

And the `@override` annotation is always optional, whether you override abstract or concrete method. All annotations are optional, since they are metadata, that are useful only to humans, compiler ignores them completely, just like comments and whitespaces.